# Periodically reboot dd-wrt

Tags: linux, router, dd-wrt

I have a Linksys Router with dd-wrt installed on. Due to some problems, I would like to periodically reboot the router (let's say at 0:00 everyday).
How would I do that?

Comment: What version of dd-wrt do you have? Make sure you have the latest version.

Answer (score 20):

dd-wrt has a scheduled reboot feature built into the firmware. Have a look at Administration >> Keep Alive >> Scheduled Reboot. Make sure cron is turned on at Administration >> Management >> Cron.

Comment: This allows weekly reboots, but doesn't work if you want to schedule less frequently. And the seconds field doesn't allow input greater than `99999`, so it also doesn't really work for less frequency than weekly.

Answer (score 6):

[if scheduled reboot does not work]

If you have enabled ssh-server on (I don't use dd-wrt, not sure if its enabled by default), you can reboot using following command

```
ssh root@192.168.1.1 reboot
```

You can look at this page to configure SSH public-private keys, so that you don't have to login everytime. And remember you should be running ssh-agent/putty-agent whereever your login from.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Telnet/SSH_and_the_Command_Line#SSH

On Linux use cron to schedule reboot, and windows use Windows-Scheduler to execute command using putty.

Comment: A lot of the smaller DD-WRT builds don't support SSH--only telnet, but it's the same basic principle.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create a cronjob for this.

Log on with `ssh` or `telnet`

Create a crontab by running:

```
# nvram set cron_jobs="00 00 * * * root reboot"
```

Commit the changes so they're still there after the first boot:

```
# nvram commit
```

Comment: In addition to Alex Toombs' answer, you can also add cron job in your router's web administration: **Administration** - **Management** tab - **Additional Cron Jobs** field: insert `00 00 * * * root reboot` (or in my case `0 3 * * 4 root reboot` so it reboots every Thursday 3:00 am).

Comment: To clarify, this shell command (`nvram set cron_jobs=...`) and the field in the Administration interface set the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Linksys WRT-54GL running DD-WRT and have the same requirement.  I've found that the scheduled reboot doesn't work so put a timer on the power outlet.  Get a digital one so you can set the downtime to be 1 minute at midnight and you have a scheduled reboot.

Comment: Huh? Which timers have settings where you can turn something off *then on* quickly? This is a modem we're talking about: he wants it turned on immediately after it is turned off.

Comment: Digital timers, like you use the schedule lamps going on and off in your house to make it look like you're at home generally can be set to a resolution of a minute or two.  A reboot cycle takes about a minute from power off to serving internet again anyway so a 2 min disruption at 3am isn't going to be too much trouble.  I've heard of UPSs that have a similar feature.

Comment: I saw chatter on the web about scheduled reboot not working, but the entry for that bug in dd-wrt's Trac site was closed as having been fixed. Do you have the latest version?

Answer (score -1):

There are low tech solutions also. You can use a light timer such as [this](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=4405611&clickid=prod_cs). They also make digital ones that are more customizable.

FYI - taken from my answer to http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=4405611&clickid=prod_cs